# A few questions about a true but unprovable statement

Tags: logic, foundations, provability

Can someone explain to me what this comment means:

> If ZFC is not a sound theory, a true but unprovable statement may be
>   refutable and therefore decidable.

- What is a *sound theory*?
- What is meant by *true but unprovable*. Isn't a true statement, one with a  proof, using premises?
- May a true statement be refutable? Does it mean that there may be a counterexample for a true statement?

Comment: A theory is sound if every provable statement is true under the intended interpretation. The intended interpretation of ZFC is one in which the variables range over all sets (in the "real world"), and the symbol $\in$ denotes the set membership relation. If you don't believe in the intended interpretation, then talk about truth and soundness is meaningless for you. If the theory is unsound, then some true statement may be refutable. No, that doesn't mean there is a counterexample. E.g., ZFC plus the axiom "ZFC is inconsistent" is widely believed to be consistent but unsound.

Comment: A counterexample to the true statement "ZFC is consistent" would be an actual proof of a contradiction in ZFC, which does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **sound theory** is one that proves only true statements. Even to speak about *whether* ZFC is sound implies that one believes there is a way for sentences in the language of set theory to be *actually true* or *actually false*, about the "actually existing sets". Or in other words, that the language of set theory has an *intended interpretation* of Platonically existing sets, such that it makes sense to ask whether the axioms are true or not.

Most working set theorists do not seem to share this belief, and would view the comment you quote as suspect. However, it still remains a somewhat respectable minority opinion, with a tacit agreement to agree to diagree about it for most practical purposes.

Less may do it, however. Even though you don't believe in the Platonic existence of an entire transfinite heirarchy of sets, you may still believe that at least the *natural numbers* exist in a Platonic sense, and that claims about *them* are objectively either true or false. (And this is a much more mainstream position to take). Then you can speak about whether ZFC is sound *with respect to arithmetic*, since there is a standard way to express claims about the natural numbers in the language of set theory. Under this interpretation, claiming that ZFC is arithmetically sound means that whenever you take a claim about the natural numbers, express it as a set-theoretic sentence and get something that has a proof in ZFC, the original claim is also true about the *actual* natural numbers.

> What is meant by *true but unprovable*. Isn't a true statement, one with a proof, using premises?

No -- as explained above the idea behind the claim is that statements can be *intrinsically* true or false, without reference to any proof system. For example we ought to recognize $2+2=4$ as a true claim, even before we begin to construct a formal system for writing and verifying proofs. Indeed, when we're designing proof systems, we're guided by a wish to be able to write proofs for statements such as $2+2=4$ that we *already know* are true -- and to *avoid* having proofs for statements that we already know are false (such as $(\exists x)x+x=1$).

On the other hand **refutable** does always refer to a specific proof system. For example, if we make an error in choosing our axioms we may end up with a system that proves the statement $\neg(2+2=4)$, that is, it *refutes* $2+2=4$. For sure, this would mean that the axiom system is *unsound*, because it proves the manifestly untrue statement $\neg(2+2=4)$. Conversely this is by definition the only way a theory in a conventional logical system *can* fail to be sound. If it proves $\varphi$ and $\varphi$ is a false statement, then $\neg\varphi$ is a true statement, and the system in question will prove $\neg\neg\varphi$, that is, refute the true statement $\neg\varphi$.

The comment you quote simply contemplates that ZFC might be unsound in this way. (Though it is not clear whether it talks about arithmetic soundness or soundness with respect to a Platonic universe of all sets).

Comment: I guess the people who don't believe that claims about natural numbers are objectively true or false may have the same doubts about whether such claims as "ZFC is consistent" are objectively true or false? But maybe they believe that *simple* statements about natural numbers are objectively true or false, and only have doubts about more complicated statements?

Comment: @bof: It strikes me as difficult to deny that, say, all closed sentences in primitive recursive arithmetic have objective truth values, but I think there are ultrafinitists who do. "ZFC is consistent" also seems too low in the arithmetical hierarchy to harbor serious doubt about -- it's $\Pi_1^0$, so either it has a counterexample or it doesn't. On the other hand, one might possibly think that PRA has objective truth values, while something like the strengthened finite Ramsey theorem doesn't.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Do you mean that we must either truly believe that *unprovable statement are not refutable* or disbelieve it?

Comment: @user795571: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Assuming our axiom system is consistent, it is not even in doubt that there exist many statements that are both unprovable and refutable -- an example would be $1\ne 1$.

Comment: @user795571: _Belief_ enters the question only when we start speaking abouth _truth_ rather than provability or refutability.

Comment: "A sound theory is one that proves only true statements." so do you mean no one knows if ZFC is sound, and if it is not sound, a false statement can be proved in it?

Comment: @user795571: Yes.

Comment: And about that false statement proved in ZFC; is it false because our heuristics say so? or is it false because there is another proof for for its negation?

Comment: @user795571: Neither. As I explain in the answer, the discussion rests on the assumption that *there is a sense in which a statement in set theory to be false **in and of itself***. That falsity is does not depend on heuristics (the assumption is that statements are true or false _independently of what we think about them_), and _certainly_ does not depend on any proofs or proof systems.